# Storing a function data into a new object and display

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

```
gettingApplyData(){
  const request = {};
  request['colAttr'] = this.columnGroupAttributes;
  request['rowAttr'] = this.rowGroupAttributes;
  request['valAttr'] = this.valueGroupAttributes;
}
```

i need to store the entire data which is in gettingApplyData() to object(lets say it is applieddata)

output:

let applieddata = gettingApplyData(); // i think this is not working

any other approach?

Comment: You forgot to add `return request;` inside `gettingApplyData` at last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to return from that function.

```
gettingApplyData(){
  const request = {};
  request['colAttr'] = this.columnGroupAttributes;
  request['rowAttr'] = this.rowGroupAttributes;
  request['valAttr'] = this.valueGroupAttributes;
  return request;
}
```

And then you can assign like this.

```
let applieddata = gettingApplyData();
```

OR

```
let applieddata = this.gettingApplyData();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the value in function:

```
gettingApplyData(){
  const request = {};
  request['colAttr'] = this.columnGroupAttributes;
  request['rowAttr'] = this.rowGroupAttributes;
  request['valAttr'] = this.valueGroupAttributes;
  return request;
}
```

Try this.